# When do we see any white-colored First Order shuttles?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, spaceship

Kylo Ren's shuttle is black:

[image: screenshot]

I don't remember seeing any white shuttles in the film, yet we have these:

- [This toy](http://www.hasbro.com/en-us/product/star-wars-episode-vii-black-series-titanium-kylo-ren-s-command-shuttle:4BCB128D-5056-9047-F50F-6B56616E2445):

  [image: white toy]
- This poster:

  [image: TFA poster]

Do we ever see any white shuttles in TFA and if so, when?

Comment: The toy is easy, that's simply a plastic model you need to paint yourself. The poster on the other hand, hm.

Comment: @MrLister - That's a Titanium Black Series collectible. You don't paint them :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### We don't

Pablo Hidalgo recently confirmed [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/812431732209131520) that, because of the different production schedules of toys versus films, the shuttle toy could not be fixed in time:

[image]

> **@stolpskott:** What about the Lego Hovertank?
>
> **@pablohidalgo:** Toys/products have a much longer lead time than books. They couldn't fix it in time. Same story behind the white Kylo shuttle.

Presumably one of the zillions of departments working on the film changed Kylo's shuttle colour, but they were unable to correct the toys in time. Such is life.

Comment: A good find. It doesn't explain all the other white items in the same range though :-)

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from this [LucasFilm-created TV advert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5Wl_9i7YI8), Ren's shuttle is actually a slate-grey in colour, rather than black. It's not impossible to imagine that the person making the poster (which is a low quality artwork that was "leaked" prior to the film's release) mistook grey for white. In [another poster by the same artist](http://film.thedigitalfix.com/protectedimage.php?image=Gallery/The_Force_Awakens_Leaked_Images_sw4.jpg_20150416&width=720), you can see that the colour balance is slightly darker and leaning much more toward a light grey.

[image]

As to the model in your picture, that's a [Titanium "Black Series" diecast model](http://www.toy-palace.com/en/titanium-diecast-fahrzeuge-black-series-2015-wave-3-sortiment-12.html). They're notorious for colouring the Empire's grey ships in white.

[image]

Comment: It it just me or it "funny" that the *Black Series* is notorious for *white*?

Comment: @Skooba - It's notorious for a bunch of other things as well such as being crap value for money and shoddily made.

Answer (score 1):

In your movie grab, Kylo Ren's shuttle isn't even as black as these birds [image: a flock of gulls against a bright sky] [from a free stock image page](https://www.videezy.com/free-video/sea-gull)

They are gulls, which are about the same colour grey as the front-lit model of the shuttle is.

I don't remember seeing the shuttle in the movie in as good lighting as the toy, only either at night or dramatically coming out of the light.

I suspect that both are supposed to be a battleship grey, and the toy is perhap a shade too light. Neither is black nor white.

Addition:

Having watched it again, I did find one scene where the shuttle is shown in decent light, and it is around 35% of the way from white objects to black objects in the scene, whereas the toy is around 95% of the way from black to white (assuming the box is black and the background white). So the toy, which claims to be the same shuttle, appears to be much too white.

[image: 35% of the way from Kylo to Stormtrooper]

Which would make the toy and movie shuttle about as different as these greys, and Valorum is right in that the toy is significantly wrong rather than just a bit wrong:
[image: 95% vs 35% grey]

Comment: -1 It may not be as "black" as the gulls, but it is definitely not white and I have no idea what your answer has to do with the question.

Comment: @DaveJohnson the question assumes that the 'white' shuttle toy and the 'black' shuttle in the movie are different colours rather than the same battleship grey colour in different lighting (though the toy is probably slightly lighter grey that the movie shuttle)

Comment: The point, though not well explained even with the example, us that lighting and background contrast are important. In the picture, the gulls look black, even though they aren't.

Comment: Have you seen the movie? The shuttle is black/very dark grey.

Comment: @RedCaio yes, and I watched it again last night. The only time it's shown in anything like decent lighting is at Takodana, the model is also only shown in much better lighting.

Answer (score 0):

[image]In the Last Jedi, we see a shuttle when Rose, Finn, and BB-8 are fleeing from the wrecked hanger of Snoke's ship (the *Supremacy*). They escape on this shuttle, and then they barely make it through the closing doors of the Crait base. We do not see any white shuttles in the Force Awakens.

Comment: Can you offer a screenshot?